# Error Install: cargo install spl-token-cli - error: could not compile `libsecp256k1`

Tags: solana-cli

I am running AWS EC2 Free Tier (t1.micro), upon running "cargo install spl-token-cli" command to install spl-token-cli my install fails towards the end, and install is abruptly ended without any error code. Is there a way to solve this?

I read that it might be a [RAM issue](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/issues/2631), but solution is not clear or what the minimum requirements are to address this.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

1. Installed Solana v1.10.31, and confirmed Solana installed. Funded SOL account from Coinbase successfully.

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.31/install)"
root:~# solana balance
0.36138418 SOL
```

2. Installed RUST and following Libraries:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
sudo apt install libudev-dev
sudo apt install libssl-dev pkg-config
sudo apt install build-essential -y
```

Reference:

```
root:~# rustc --version
rustc 1.62.1 (e092d0b6b 2022-07-16)
```

3. Ran "install spl-token-cli" received error

```
error: could not compile \`libsecp256k1\`
```

Full Error, received around 450/483

```
error: could not compile `libsecp256k1`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc --crate-name libsecp256k1 --edition=2018 /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/libsecp256k1-0.5.0/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C opt-level=3 -C embed-bitcode=no --cfg 'feature="default"' --cfg 'feature="hmac"' --cfg 'feature="hmac-drbg"' --cfg 'feature="sha2"' --cfg 'feature="static-context"' --cfg 'feature="std"' --cfg 'feature="typenum"' -C metadata=f119b9f1bc16e764 -C extra-filename=-f119b9f1bc16e764 --out-dir /tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps -L dependency=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps --extern arrayref=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libarrayref-d72b1a7e9fc58035.rmeta --extern base64=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libbase64-9aac25c5f1796611.rmeta --extern digest=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libdigest-cf697cf6bf7ada0c.rmeta --extern hmac_drbg=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libhmac_drbg-09dac8b239e348c6.rmeta --extern libsecp256k1_core=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/liblibsecp256k1_core-80357b39155ca295.rmeta --extern rand=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/librand-7689b79fd2bbb12c.rmeta --extern serde=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libserde-981cc0b8bda5ddb7.rmeta --extern sha2=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libsha2-4657e764233274db.rmeta --extern typenum=/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba/release/deps/libtypenum-3d00a21487da8bed.rmeta --cap-lints allow` (signal: 9, SIGKILL: kill)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `spl-token-cli v2.0.15`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-install5kkhba`
```

Comment: You should include more relevant errors as 'error: could not compile' is too general. You should have more detailed error few lines above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing if you check the output of `dmesg` after the compilation fails, you'd see messages from `oom-killer` reaping it.  Typically this can be gotten around by limiting build parallelization with `--jobs N` where `N` is some number less than the output of `nproc`.  For core development, we usually use `N = TOTAL_RAM_GB / 3`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully install "spl-token-cli" using the "cargo install spl-token-cli" after upgrading my server from t1.micro to t2.small. I am still not clear on the minimum requirement to run "spl-token-cli", however this worked.

**AWS EC2 instance:**

- **t1.micro *(free tier)*** includes 1GB RAM/Memory - **did NOT work**
- **t2.small** includes 2GB RAM/Memory - **this DID work**

[image: Example of Fully Compiled CLI]

Comment: I ran into an unrelated problem when running "spl-token create-token" on Ubuntu 22.04. According to this question/answer run wget and sudo dppkg command  to get most recent "libssl" files. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378647/spl-token-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-1-1-cannot-open-shar ...This fixes it (a problem with packaging in 22.04):